# Citizenship and Expatriate marriage

Tags: indian-citizens, dual-citizenship, pakistani-citizen, uae

I am in love with a Pakistani guy and we two are planning to get married. But none of us want to give up our citizenship because we fear that our love will be ruined by the dirty politics of both countries. We are planning to get married in UAE shariya court. We just wanted to know about the citizenship for our child. Without giving our own citizenship can we get Saudi citizenship for our child if we raise him/her together.... Anyone please help us please we are in very need of this.

---

We are planning to get marry in UAE and also settle in UAE

Comment: Where do you and your fiancé live?  Where do you plan to live after you marry?  Is the child you're asking about already born?  If so, where; if not, where do you expect the child to be born?

Comment: I am an Indian girl My fiance is from Pakistan... We are planning to get marry in Dubai and we expect our child to get UAE Or Arabian citizenship.

Comment: Where do you plan to live after getting married?

Comment: While expats can now be nominated for Emirati citizenship, it's still going to be [difficult to obtain](https://u.ae/en/information-and-services/passports-and-traveling/emirati-nationality).